# Resizing system partition

Tags: partition, filesystem, efi

When I installed OSX Mavericks, I left free space after my system partition in case I wanted to install a second OS there.  This has proved unnecessary — I've never modified the partition table — and I'd like to integrate that space into my `system` partition.

In theory, this can be done quite easily with Disk Utility.  However, this does not seem to work for me.  When I select the Partition tab for the drive in Disk Utility, I see a small unnamed partition at the top, followed by my system partition, followed by blank space.  There is a pull-tab at the bottom right of the `system` partition.  I can pull that tab down to fill the empty space with the `system` partition.  However, when I hit `Apply` and confirm, the message "Preparing to partition disk" shows up next to a barber-pole wait indicator and never goes away.

Answers to other questions suggest that this issue can be resolved by running `Verify` and `Repair` on both the system partition and the drive on which it is located.  `Verify` on the partition shows no errors; `Verify` on the drive indicates that it doesn't have an EFI partition — a problem which `Repair` proves unable to fix.

Running `$ diskutil list` from the command line reveals the following partitions:

- 0: The GPT
- 1: The small partition is labeled `Microsoft Reserved`; I [gather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) that this is set up by OSX install to facilitate possible later Boot Camp installation.
- 2: There is an EFI partition (!) located between the `Microsoft Reserved` partition and the `system` partition
- 3: `system` partition
- 4: Recovery partition

`diskutil` doesn't explicitly indicate the location of these partitions, so I installed the `brew` package `gptfdisk` and ran `sgdisk -p`, which confirmed that the Recovery partition is located direction after `system`.

**SO:**  My hypothesis is that Disk Utility is unable to grow the `system` partition because there is a partition immediately following it.  If this is the case, I'm confused as to why the OSX installer would put it there instead of at the end of the disk.  But anyway: if this is really the issue, what's the easiest, and preferably free, way to move it to the end of the disk?  I could use `dd` to get it there, but I'm unaware of any tools that can reliably edit the partition table.  (`sgdisk` could do this, but the `brew` version is 0.8.something, so I don't really trust it.)

Are there any special things I need to keep in mind when changing the partition table?  There seems to be something wrong with it already (given the EFI issue).

It's looking like I'll need to set up a rescue boot disk, so recommendations on those are gladly accepted.

### EDIT: Question is a tome already but somebody asked for output so here it is:

```
$ diskutil list /dev/disk0
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *512.1 GB   disk0
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk0s1
   2:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS system                  319.2 GB   disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s4

$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
Password:
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34      262144      1  GPT part - [GUID REDACTED]
      262178        2014         
      264192      409600      2  GPT part - [GUID REDACTED]
      673792   623464448      3  GPT part - [GUID REDACTED]
   624138240     1269760      4  GPT part - [GUID REDACTED]
   625408000   374807183         
  1000215183          32         Sec GPT table
  1000215215           1         Sec GPT header

$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0        geometry: 62260/255/63 [1000215216 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 - 1000215215] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: What had posted so far is great, but it would be easier if you would run the following commands in a Terminal window and copy/paste the results to your posted question. The commands are `diskutil  list`, `sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0` and `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0`. None of these commands will change your computer. Some will ask for your login password. This is normal.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: hmm maybe I did more customization of the partition scheme than I remembered.  Is it normal to not be able to grow the system partition using Disk Utility when the Recovery partition directly follows it?  What's the proper procedure to grow the system partition in that case?

Comment: The `Microsoft Reserved` partition was not created by any OS X software. It should not exist on your Mac. The `Recovery HD` partition correctly occurs after the `system` partition. The Disk Utility relocates `Recovery HD` partition when the `system` partition is resized. So your hypothesis is wrong. Most likely the existence of the 'Microsoft Reserved' partition is causing the Disk Utility application to hang.

Comment: It IS normal to grow/shrink a Mac OS Extended partition (48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC) whether or not it is followed by a Recovery partition (426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC). You have to choices. Either remove the Microsoft reserved partition and see if that fixes the problem. Or, backup the system and Recovery HD partitions to an external device, repartition the disk, then restore from back up. (You probably should backup regardless of your choice.)

Comment: Are you sure you waited long enough? It does take quite sometime for the Disk Utility to move the Recovery Partition to the end of the disk. The actual enlarging of the system partition takes no time at all.

Comment: Hmm any idea  how to get rid of the `Microsoft Reserved` partition?  I selected it in Disk Utility and hit the - button and confirmed but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: I'll try waiting longer to see if the `Preparing to partition disk` notice goes away.  Just started another attempt to grow the `System` partition a minute ago.

Comment: It's still showing `Preparing to partition disk`.  The partition is only 650MB and the install is on an SSD, so it definitely should have finished moving the partition by now.

Comment: It's still showing the same message.  Definitely not a matter of waiting for it to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up [setting up an Ubuntu USB boot drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick), rebooting into Ubuntu, and using `gparted` to write a new partition table that changed the partition type of the `Microsoft Recovery` to ext4 and named it.  I also formatted that partition to ext4.

After rebooting back into my OSX install, I was able to resize the `system` partition.  Yay!