# Can't re-enable FileVault after growing `system` partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, filevault

I recently disabled FileVault in order to grow my system partition.  This ended up being [rather more complicated than expected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/resizing-system-partition/198068#198068), but it worked out in the end.

Now that I have resized the system partition, I want to re-encrypt my drive, but I'm getting this error when I attempt to engage FileVault:

```
FileVault can't be turned on for the disk "system".

Some disk formats don't support the recovery partition required by encryption.
To use encryption, reinstall this version of Mac OS X on a reformatted disk.
```

This is strange, since the disk has a recovery partition — it was actually moved by Disk Utility in the process of growing the `system` partition.  Here's what `diskutil` and `gpt` have to say about it:

```
$ diskutil list disk0
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *512.1 GB   disk0
   1:       Microsoft Basic Data                         134.2 MB   disk0s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS system                  511.1 GB   disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s5

$ sudo gpt show /dev/disk0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34      262144      1  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
      262178        2014
      264192      409600      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
      673792   998271624      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   998945416     1269760      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1000215176           7
  1000215183          32         Sec GPT table
  1000215215           1         Sec GPT header
```

Hmm, turns out I now have two EFI partitions.  Apparently Disk Utility decided to change the partition type of my ext4 partition without consulting me.  What a jerk.

**EDIT**: just noticed this [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101192/cant-enable-filevault-because-recovery-partition-missing).  Not exactly the same, since that person is not trying to do full-disk encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to streamline the partitioning scheme as much as possible.  I deleted my leading, unused partition, but this still didn't make it go.

Somehow the partition type of the EFI partition had gotten changed, so I decided to fix that.  There doesn't seem to be any obvious way to do this from within OSX, so I rebooted off of a [live Ubuntu boot image on a USB drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick).  I used `gdisk` to set the type of the EFI partition to `EF`, and confirmed that this had also correctly changed its GUID to the [correct one for that partition type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition#cite_ref-uefi-spec-2.5_1-1).

For some reason, under linux the names of the EFI and Recovery partitions had disappeared, so I set them back to the names shown above.  I also confirmed that there was a FAT32 filesystem on the EFI partition.  Apparently the EFI filesystem [is technically a different one from FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition#cite_ref-uefi-spec-2.5_1-1) but I left it as it was.

And it worked!  When I booted back to OSX, I ran Verify on the disk in Disk Utility, which recommended that I run Repair due to some "corruption" in the Recovery Partition, or perhaps just with its header.  I ran Repair, which reported success, and was then able to initiate full-disk FileVault encryption.